# How add the image alt attribute in all images in the wordpress gallery?

Tags: wordpress

I want to add the alt attribute in the output of a [gallery] shortcode e.g. Now the source code looks like this:

```
<dt class="gallery-icon landscape"><img width="150" height="84" src="//" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail" alt="" srcset=".....
```

As you can see the attribute alt is empty.

How add the image alt attribute in every image in the gallery wordpress?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R52d0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

When placing the image via the admin, click on the image, then 'edit' (maybe pencil icon) and then on the image properties you can add the ALT tag. Fill all the information there and see how it affects your code

Comment: All my images with the alt attribute filled. When images are uploaded, alt and title attributes are automatically filled.